# R 3.1.1 (32-bit): htmlParse() mess up hebrew texts, OS: Win 7

Tags: r, encoding, html-parsing, hebrew, rcurl

Trying to parse an Hebrew .HTML webpage, and having problems using RCurl tools for that purpose. I've been reading the followings:

- [Getting htmlParse to work with hebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061619/getting-htmlparse-to-work-with-hebrew)
- [Extracting a clean "UTF-8" text from a web page scraped with RCurl (this one works for Japenese, but the solution there won't fit my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069908/r-extracting-clean-utf-8-text-from-a-web-page-scraped-with-rcurl)
- [R-Help: getting htmlParse to work with Hebrew (on Windows)](http://thr3ads.net/r-help/2012/01/1832938-Getting-htmlParse-to-work-with-Hebrew-on-windows)

I have used the following R code:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url_get<-"http://www.agora.co.il/toGet.asp?searchType=searchAll&amp;dealType=1&amp;dealStatus=1"
download.file(url_get, "codes/tmp.html")
txt <- readLines("codes/tmp.html", encoding="UTF-8")
pagetree <- htmlParse(txt, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
```

While readLines() produces proper Hebrew (**בעלי מקצוע**);

```
 txt[345]
[1] "<a id=\"professionals\" href=\"/texts/midrag.asp?parameter=\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"בעלי מקצוע\">"
```

the htmlParse() mess it up (**׳•׳— ׳—׳₪׳¦׳™ ׳™׳“ ׳©׳ ׳™׳” ׳׳׳¡׳™׳¨׳” ׳‘׳—׳™׳ ׳ ׳‘׳׳‘׳“**).

```
    <a href="http://shlah.agora.co.il/financial/financial1.html">׳׳¦׳׳× ׳׳”׳׳™׳ ׳•׳¡</a><br><br><span class="linkWords">׳׳•׳— ׳—׳₪׳¦׳™ ׳™׳“ ׳©׳ ׳™׳” ׳׳׳¡׳™׳¨׳” ׳‘׳—׳™׳ ׳ ׳‘׳׳‘׳“ -
```

Any ideas?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255    LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.3 bitops_1.0-6   XML_3.98-1.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: What is the url you downloaded the file from? Without that it's impossible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @hadley you are right. Thanks. I have editted the URL into the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem. Here are the steps I took:

1. First try a very simple HTML 5 document:

   ```
   library(XML)

   # This is the simplest valid HTML-5
   # http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2010/a-minimal-html5-document/
   hebrew1 <- "
     <!doctype html>
     <title>בעלי מקצו</title>
   "

   htmlParse(hebrew1) # NOT OK
   #> <!DOCTYPE html>
   #> <html><head><title>××¢×× ××§×¦×</title></head></html>
   #> 
   htmlParse(hebrew1, encoding = "UTF-8") # OK
   #> <!DOCTYPE html>
   #> <html><head><title>בעלי מקצו</title></head></html>
   #> 

   hebrew2 <- "
     <!doctype html>
     <meta charset=utf-8>
     <title>בעלי מקצו</title>
   "
   htmlParse(hebrew2) # OK
   #> <!DOCTYPE html>
   #> <html><head>
   #> <meta charset="utf-8">
   #> <title>בעלי מקצו</title>
   #> </head></html>
   #>
   ```
2. Try directly from URL:

   ```
   url <- "http://www.agora.co.il/toGet.asp?searchType=searchAll&amp;dealType=1&amp;dealStatus=1"
   html <- htmlParse(url, encoding = "UTF-8")
   XML::getNodeSet(html, "//a")[[1]]
   #> <a href="/signIn.asp?source=signIn">התחבר/י</a>
   ```
3. Load from disk:

   ```
   tmp <- tempfile()
   download.file(url, tmp)
   html <- htmlParse(tmp, encoding = "UTF-8")
   XML::getNodeSet(html, "//a")[[1]]
   #> <a href="/signIn.asp?source=signIn">התחבר/י</a>
   ```
4. Load from lines

   ```
   lines <- readLines(tmp)
   html <- htmlParse(lines, encoding = "UTF-8")
   XML::getNodeSet(html, "//a")[[1]]
   #> <a href="/signIn.asp?source=signIn">התחבר/י</a>
   ```

Comment: Thanks @hadley
It worked. Yet I found it strange that the the very simple HTML-5 example didn't work, and messed up the language, while the others have worked. I uses exactly the code you presented.
In addition, when I print the htmlParse file from the other methods it still messes up the text; only by using `XML::getNodeSet(html,"//a")[[1]]` the hebrew seems to work well
Does someone have an idea why?

Comment: @dof1985 I suspect it's just a printing problem. The class of the two things are different so they probably have different printing methods and probably one has a bug in it.